# syntax issue with python groupby using a variable mixed with a list or string

Tags: python, syntax, pandas, group-by

I am trying to run a groupby that includes a variable and a string combined to use as the grouped fields/columns. can someone help with the syntax it is one of those things that will probably take me a day to figure out.

```
Mix ='business_unit','isoname','planning_channel','is_tracked','planning_partner','week'
```

So the below works:

```
dfJoinsP2 = dfJoinsP2.groupby(Mix)['joined_subs_cmap', 'initial_billed_subs', 'billed_d1', 'churn_d1' , 'churn_24h'].sum().reset_index()
```

But when I try and add an extra field called 'Period_Number' I get an error.

```
dfJoinsP2 = dfJoinsP2.groupby(Mix,'Period_Number')['joined_subs_cmap', 'initial_billed_subs', 'billed_d1', 'churn_d1' , 'churn_24h'].sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: Are we talking about *Pandas* groupby on a dataframe here?

Comment: Please, always include the full error message (traceback) when asking about code that produces an error. Don't leave answerers guessing.

Comment: If you want to groupby by an additional column you need to add it to your list, by passing it like you do it cannot match this against any of the other optional args see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby)

Comment: The other point here is that effectively you have created a tuple by the way you declared `Mix`, you'd be better off making this a list initially so you can append to it like so: `Mix =['business_unit','isoname','planning_channel','is_tracked','planning_partner','week']
Mix.append('Period Number')`

Comment: good point Martijn Pieters I won't be so lazy for next time ;) and yes it was a pandas groupby and the error was as in EdChum's working solution. Thanks again EdChum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to recreate and illustrate your problem:

```
In [22]:
# define our cols, create a dummy df
cols = ['business_unit','isoname','planning_channel','is_tracked','planning_partner','week','joined_subs_cmap', 'initial_billed_subs', 'billed_d1', 'churn_d1' , 'churn_24h', 'Period Number']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, data =np.random.randn(5, len(cols)))
df
Out[22]:
   business_unit   isoname  planning_channel  is_tracked  planning_partner  \
0      -0.818644  1.150678         -0.860677   -0.333496         -0.292689   
1       0.476575 -0.018507         -1.917119    0.360656          0.381106   
2       1.187570  1.105363          1.955066    0.154020          1.996389   
3       0.318762  0.962469          0.565538    0.671002         -0.675688   
4      -0.070671 -1.717793         -0.085815    0.089589          0.892412   

       week  joined_subs_cmap  initial_billed_subs  billed_d1  churn_d1  \
0 -0.681875          1.138119            -1.071672   0.409712 -1.066456   
1 -0.235040          0.559950             0.082890  -0.372671  0.804438   
2  1.707340          0.893437             0.316266   1.852508 -2.554488   
3 -2.055322          1.848388            -1.695563  -0.826089 -0.588229   
4 -0.325098          0.827455             0.535827  -0.930963  0.211628   

   churn_24h  Period Number  
0   1.067530       0.377579  
1   0.097042      -1.947681  
2  -0.327243      -1.137146  
3   0.230110       1.470183  
4   1.191042       2.167251  
In [23]:
# what you are trying to do
Mix ='business_unit','isoname','planning_channel','is_tracked','planning_partner','week'
df.groupby(Mix, 'Period Number')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-dc75b3902303> in <module>()
      1 Mix ='business_unit','isoname','planning_channel','is_tracked','planning_partner','week'
----> 2 df.groupby(Mix, 'Period Number')

C:\WinPython-64bit-3.3.3.2\python-3.3.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in groupby(self, by, axis, level, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze)
   2894         if level is None and by is None:
   2895             raise TypeError("You have to supply one of 'by' and 'level'")
-> 2896         axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
   2897         return groupby(self, by=by, axis=axis, level=level, as_index=as_index,
   2898                        sort=sort, group_keys=group_keys, squeeze=squeeze)

C:\WinPython-64bit-3.3.3.2\python-3.3.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_axis_number(self, axis)
    294                 pass
    295         raise ValueError('No axis named {0} for object type {1}'
--> 296                          .format(axis, type(self)))
    297 
    298     def _get_axis_name(self, axis):

ValueError: No axis named Period Number for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

So you get a ValueError because 'Period Number' is being interpreted as an [axis](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html) value which is of course invalid and not what you intended.

The other point here is that the way you defined Mix will result in a tuple, if instead it was a list then we could append the additional column of interest and all would be fine:

```
In [24]:

Mix = ['business_unit','isoname','planning_channel','is_tracked','planning_partner','week']
Mix.append('Period Number')
df.groupby(Mix)['joined_subs_cmap', 'initial_billed_subs', 'billed_d1', 'churn_d1' , 'churn_24h'].sum().reset_index()
Out[24]:
   business_unit   isoname  planning_channel  is_tracked  planning_partner  \
0      -0.818644  1.150678         -0.860677   -0.333496         -0.292689   
1      -0.070671 -1.717793         -0.085815    0.089589          0.892412   
2       0.318762  0.962469          0.565538    0.671002         -0.675688   
3       0.476575 -0.018507         -1.917119    0.360656          0.381106   
4       1.187570  1.105363          1.955066    0.154020          1.996389   

       week  Period Number  joined_subs_cmap  initial_billed_subs  billed_d1  \
0 -0.681875       0.377579          1.138119            -1.071672   0.409712   
1 -0.325098       2.167251          0.827455             0.535827  -0.930963   
2 -2.055322       1.470183          1.848388            -1.695563  -0.826089   
3 -0.235040      -1.947681          0.559950             0.082890  -0.372671   
4  1.707340      -1.137146          0.893437             0.316266   1.852508   

   churn_d1  churn_24h  
0 -1.066456   1.067530  
1  0.211628   1.191042  
2 -0.588229   0.230110  
3  0.804438   0.097042  
4 -2.554488  -0.327243
```

Comment: Thanks EdChum for your complete workings and solution. I guess I thought I could manipulate the Variable list somehow within the groupby. I can work with manipulating the list or at least having two or more lists referencing them when needed or I could append to the list like you have and then remove on other occasions.